# What are the L, a, b ranges?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-image

When converting RGB to Lab as in:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2lab
import skimage.io as io
rgb = io.imread(...)[:,:,:3]
lab = rgb2lab(rgb)
```

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1185

Answer (score 0):

[Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space):

> Each axis of each square ranges from −128 to 128.